# Is it possible to reference the same CTE in more than one unrelated query?

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression

I have this CTE1 that I'd like to reference it in 2 or more unrelated queries

```
WITH CTE1
AS
(
  SELECT col1, col2, col3
  FROM Table1
  WHERE condition 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE1;

SELECT * FROM CTE1 c // This is not working -- Invalid object name 'CTE1'.
JOIN TABLE2 t
ON c.colx = t.xolx;
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks for helping

Comment: no, you should use temp table, table variable or view instead

Comment: I tried table variable and it worked. Thanks